# What is this ensemble learning technique called?

Tags: ensemble-learning

For example, I trained two models: one with SVM and one with KNN.

```
Final Prediction = 0.4*KNN + 0.6*SVM
```

Is this considered blending?

Comment: You can call it ensemble model.

Comment: But there is no official term for this? Is this unheard of?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can call that blending.  You could also call it a weighted average of two models.

Comment: A side note: Why isn't this technique used widely? Is it because it is hard to find the appropriate weights?

Comment: @user1008537 why do you think it's any good? You lose any theoretical properties of all approaches you're blending and end up with a droopy mess.

Comment: @user1008537 It is widely used.  One easy way to find appropriate weights is through cross-validation.  You can do a regression on the held-out data to find the weights.  This is called a "second-stage model" or "meta model"

Comment: @MarcClaesen [If your primary modeling goal is predictive accuracy](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/), theoretical properties of individual models is far less important. In this case blending is often an excellent approach: the strengths of one model can make up for the weaknesses of another.